# Isolated critical point and Hessian matrix (doubt in a passage of the proof)

Tags: real-analysis, hessian-matrix

I have read the question posed in [Non degenerated critical points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143594/are-non-degenerate-critical-points-always-isolated) and checking the proof given in the accepted answer (I can not use Morse lemma) a question arose in my mind. The idea of the proof is clear althought I have a question on it.
Suppose you want to prove that if the determinant of the Hessian matrix at a critical point (that is supposed to be $0$) is not $0$ then the critical point is isolated.
Suppose by contradiction that the point is not isolated.
The author of the answer consider all curves $\gamma$ (and then straight lines) through the point and then correcly state that
$$
(f|_{\gamma})=(\gamma'(t))^T\,H(\gamma'(t))
$$
that in case of a straight line becomes
$$
(f|_{\gamma})''=v^TH\,v
$$
I do not understant why in this case necessarily $f$ must have a local extremum and then the zero of $f'$ has to be isolated.

Any help will be very appreciated.